# is it possible to add a reference to other browsers in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The web browser in vb.net is using IE or maybe its not even a web browser. Maybe its the primitive browser in windows that came before IE.
Is it possible to change the browser that is used by the vb.net web browser(dragged from the toolbox)? Maybe through the add reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't change the browsing engine used by the `WebBrowser` control, but there's certainly nothing stopping you (or anyone else) from writing a different control in the same vein that uses an alternative rendering engine (say, Gecko).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% but I'd say this it just reused the DLL's that make up the IE installed locally. I would have said the answer to your question is no.